# Backup/Copy pip modules from folder structure

Tags: python

My laptop recently died, and while there are easy ways to backup modules on a working system ([for example](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5j4pld/is_there_a_way_to_backup_python_module_packages/)), I wasn't intelligent enough to do so.

I do, however, have a very recent backup of the entire Python folder. I can't execute that python version anymore, seeing as I'm on a new, freshly installed windows system. So my question is:

Is there an elegant way to tell Python (2.7.5 AND 3.6.1) to install all the modules I already had inside the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/install/index.html) says modules are installed here:
[image: Default lib paths]

So you should be able to copy old modules from your python folder to this folder. I am not sure if it will work for all modules, cos they may be incompatible with your new version. I strongly suggest to create a BACKUP.

Another way could be modifying `sys.path` in your script, so Python will search for modules also in the path provided by you:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/old/libs/folder')
```

If these methods don't work for all your libs, they can at least serve you as a temporary fix until you find a better way to detect and install all old libs with new version.

Comment: this worked well, and when it didn't, a quick reinstall using pip was possible. thank you!